# AOSP build emulator does not start/shows black screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

I have a problem with the Android-Emulator which I builded from the AOSP.

My Steps are:

```
$ repo sync -j8
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch --> chose 22. aosp_x86_64-eng
$ make -j8
$ set_stuff_for_environment
$ emulator
```

Then the emulator start but stays with a black screen and after a long time of nothing it does not response. I also tried it with other targets like  `1. aosp_arm-eng`

Every other emulator is start (over AVD Manager or Android Studio) works as usual.

I use macOS 10.14.6